# What web server is embedded in ArcGIS 10.1 for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

Esri seems to have a new embedded webserver in ArcGIS 10.1 for Server.

Does anyone know what technology they have used to build it?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tomcat. No idea if it is the same as the ArcGIS runtime API. I'll check the jar files late today.

Comment: As a sidenote, the 10 Java edition also had an embedded Tomcat and also Apache Derby for the security store.

Comment: So is AGS 10.1 backend all written in Java then?

Comment: Id recommend asking that as a separate Q